# Importing a python module works in cmd but not in an IDE (pycharm)

Tags: python, module, pycharm

I downloaded the gTTS module via pip in command prompt, and after running python in cmd I could use the command:

```
from GTTS import gtts
```

and it would work. However this same command does not work in my pycharm IDE, where it places a red line under GTTS and gtts, stating that they are 'unresolved references'.

I have done no steps following the initial download, since I wouldn't really know what to do

Comment: if you have anaconda installed, you need to do a pip install from anaconda prompt.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Is there an error message?

Comment: @smiley It states that they are unresolved references

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a case of setting up Pycharm to pick up the references.

Go to Pycharm->Preferences->Project->Project Interpreter

Depending on your setup, you can either choose the appropriate interpreter (dropdown at top) or add the GTTS package (+ at bottom, search for GTTS in window that pops up and choose Install)